# Class decimal.InvalidOperation Error

Tags: python, matrix, decimal, multiplication

I am multiplying two matrixes 3x3 and 1x3.

```
import decimal
dec = decimal.Decimal

dot = [0.0,0.0,0.0]
J = [1.0,2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0]
F = [0.0,1.0,2.0]

for i in range(3):
  dot[i] = dec(J[i][0])*dec(F[0])+dec(J[i][1])*dec(F[1])+dec(J[i][2])*dec(F[2])
```

The code works but after few iterations of the matrixes values, I get this error:

```
<ipython-input-2-58067b4f3a4e> in DotProduct(J, F)
      9 def DotProduct(J,F):
     10     for i in range(3):
---> 11      dot[i] = dec(J[i][0]) * dec(F[0]) + dec(J[i][1]) 
               * dec(F[1]) + dec(J[i][2]) * dec(F[2])
     12     return dot
     13 

InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

These are original inputs (from different calculations performed earlier)

**J (3x3) Matrix (original)**

```
([Decimal('0.1379312608303500019037507171'), 
Decimal('-0.1221574827527377810270231013'), 
Decimal('0E+30')], 
[Decimal('-0.03195193407702472679971126508'), 
Decimal('0.03257150032372060736589472552'), 
Decimal('-0E+30')], 
[Decimal('0E+30'), 
Decimal('-0E+30'),  
Decimal('0.001941217285022088082028050212')])
```

**F (1x3) Matrix (Original)**

```
[ 0.33484765  0.37611522  5.50589724]
```

**dot (1x3) Matrix-result of J*F**

```
[Decimal('0.00024067027981818560724074545'), 
Decimal('0.00155160691687072804459308826'), 
Decimal('0.01068814288621735926754972657')]
```

After many iterations:

**J matrix becomes**

```
([Decimal('-2.017921396484441390463202074E-285'), 
Decimal('1.544790144766561273091342077E-337'), 
Decimal('-0')], 
[Decimal('-0.03736963129288584732273158647'), 
Decimal('0.03736963129288584732273158647'), 
Decimal('0')], 
[Decimal('0'), 
Decimal('-0'), 
Decimal('0.001941217285022090055061872254')])
```

**F Matrix becomes**

```
[ -3.02323763e+229  -3.80160157e+281  -1.44050757e+308]
```

**dot Matrix becomes**

```
[Decimal('2.27979261759690205166387891E-57'), 
Decimal('-1.420644490442869792721270372E+280'), 
Decimal('-2.796338188825434810994646950E+305')]
```

Comment: What is `dec`??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga dec = decimal.Decimal

Comment: You should make that clear in the question itself. You should strive to post code that people can run without modifying.

Comment: and what is `dot` ?

Comment: @alfasin dot is an array for 1x3 matrix, it holds the result multiplication of 3x3 and 1x3 matrixes.

Comment: @Lidka I think you mean a *list*

Comment: @Lidka can you print the **full stack trace**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure what you mean by **full stack trace** Sorry, but I am new both to Python and stack overflow community. I am rewriting VBA program that I have developed to the Python. VBA works perfectly but when I do the same thing in Python I get different results. Long story short, this is the last error that I am running into and cannot figure a way out. I have to use decimal.Decimal to maintain accuracy of the program.

Comment: I mean the *full error message*.

Comment: print out what `dot` is before you do the assign. I think it might be a list with another list inside it.

Comment: @AaronTaggart I added original inputs and final right before the error.

Comment: Putting those values into the equation given doesn't produce the error. How is J matrix changing? How is F matrix changing? The code you posted doesn't change these values at all. You need to post the minimal amount of code that can actually reproduce the issue. The issue is not in the code you have posted, it is in the code you have not posted. Why is the output of F matrix different than the output of the other matrix?